# get previous date in J2ME

Tags: java-me

I want to get the date of previous month in J2ME.

I have found this code :

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();  
c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1); //one year back  
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);// then one month
```

but this is working in Java SE not J2ME, please if anyone can help me find the corresponding method or class in J2ME?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calendar does not have method add.

```
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, -1)
```

Means you set value -1 at field MONTH.
Your solution is

```
    // get current month
    int m = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    // decrement it
    if (--m < 0) {
        // if was january, must become december of past year
        m = 11;
        // set year to previous
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, c.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1);
    }
    // set new value "m" to field MONTH
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, m);
```

Please refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html
for documentation. You should't work without it unless you know all you need.